# Are TI TMS320C6x and TI TMS320C2x compatible?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, signal-processing, dsp

I never learnt assembly language programming. But, I know C and C++.

I need to learn C2000 Piccolo programming. I found no book on C2000, there are only manuals from TI website.

But, suddenly, [I found this book](https://tungvp.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/dsp-applications-using-c-and-the-tms320c6x-dsk.pdf).

I only have 02 months in my hand to learn this C2000 thing. Would it be worth reading, if I want to learn C2000 Piccolo programming? Or, would it be a waste of time.

Answer (score 5):

There is a big difference between C6000 and C2000.

Mainly, C6000 is a DSP (very high speed, starting from 456 MHz) and, as it is a DSP, it's more focused on signal processing.

C2000 is more like a general MCU (freq. range in 60-200 MHz). PWM and ADC is the main core of C2000 (strongest side). C2000 is focused on power electronics (motor control, power inverters). So I would say they are very different, although I personally have experience only with C2000.

Anyway, it's quite a challenge to learn any of them in 2 months, both are complex. But if you need to learn C2000 then go for C2000 and definitely not for a C6000. On C2000 you need pure C for 90-99% of your code.

I would start with a [TI C2000 workshops](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/C2000_Archived_Workshops) as a starting point. But you definitely need a launchpad (real chip) to try your code. The easiest and simplest MCU to start with is is TMS320F28027 ([link to the launchpad](http://www.ti.com/tool/launchxl-f28027)).
You can ask specific questions directly on TI C2000 forum (btw, there was a [similar thread](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/471421) a couple of days ago).

Comment: My main question was, whether I would be able to consolidate my knowledge of C6000 to program C2000 given that I didn't find any book of C2000. The link you provided are already checked by me. Those are described in highly technical and abstract languages and are only suitable for people who already worked on such chips for a long time or who has some mentor.

Comment: Have you looked into the book that you have linked in your first post? The main chapters are "FIR Filters", "IIR Filters", "FFT", "Adaptive Filters", etc. These are extremely interesting topics to study, but they are much more relevant for DSP, not for general MCU. So it all depends on what is your goal. Also, I don't agree that the Workshop is " described in highly technical and abstract language". There are Student Guides, take a look [at this for instance](http://software-dl.ti.com/trainingTTO/trainingTTO_public_sw/c28x280271day/C28x1DayWorkshop.pdf)